# How load libsvm data file into numpy array to be used for kmeans clustering in sciki-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, libsvm

I need to do clustering on a libsvm format data file, I know that we can load data using X,y = sklearn.datasets.load_svmlight_file(dataFilename). This returns X as a sparse matrix. Is there any way to load data into numpy array or convert X to dense array.
Note: data format as follows:
 : :....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether you want the output dense matrix to be in form of an array or a matrix, you can call either `toarray()` or `todense()` function of the resulting CSR (CSC) scipy matrix. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html for more details.